# Mapbox GL - draw and animate several points/symbols

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to add real-time, web-socket event-based data to my map.
Everytime I get a point, I must add it/update it on map.
What's the best option?

A) Create a FeatureCollection and add a source and respective layer. When updating, change the FeatureCollection and call setData();
B) For every point, create a different source and layer. When updating, just change the respective source and call setData();

I really don't believe B) is the best option, I'm just not sure about the perfomance of option A) (or I'm thinking about the former the wrong way).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it somewhere between the two. For Mapbox Draw I use two layers, one for features that are being edited and one for features that aren't changing. In your case, you'd want to create a layer for every 100 features. This is because Mapbox GL has to recut the geojson into tiles every time you add a feature so limiting the number of features that have to be reviewed is wise. That said, lots of layers will be a problem too.

While I said 100 features above, you'll want to play around with this number a bunch. It will be about finding the right balance between number of layers and number of features in a source.